# Can't set audio bitrate

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am converting some high quality Apple ProRes files to H.264. Everything works but the audio bit rate. What is the correct way to do this? Ffmpeg command line:

```
-i source.mov
    -vcodec h264
    -b:v 10000K
    -b:a 96K
    -acodec pcm_s24le
    -pix_fmt yuv420p
    -threads 0
    -ac 2
    destination.mov
```

ffprobe reports audio stream as:

> Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz,
>   stereo, s32 (24 bit), **2304 kb/s (default)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the output codec to `pcm_s24le` which is by definition a raw, lossless and uncompressed audio format. Its bitrate depends only on the sample rate and number of channels. The parameter `-b:a` is as such ignored.

If you want to be able to set a bitrate, you need to choose a lossy codec such as [AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) or [MP3](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: `libvo_aacenc` works.